# Again the Shift Function and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $s\in\mathbb{R}_+$ be arbitraryn and assume the following for a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of functions in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$:

- $\exists M>0\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}{|f_n(x)|}\leq M$ (the functionsequence is uniformly bounded)
- $\forall K\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ \text{compact}\ \forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq N: \sup_{x\in K}{|f_n(x)|}<\varepsilon$ (the sequence converges to zero in the compact open topology (as locally convex topology genereted by seminorms))

What I want to prove now is the following:
 $$\forall t\in[0,s]\ \forall K\subseteq\mathbb{R}\ \text{compact}\ \forall\varepsilon>0\ \exists N'\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq N': \sup_{x\in K}{|f_n(x+t)|}<\varepsilon$$

My intuition says the following to me: take $t\in[0,s]$, $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ compact and $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. We can have two situations: the first one is that the shiftes functions $f_n$ for $n\geq N$ has already the supremum lower $\varepsilon$, in this case we can choose $N'=N$. The second case seems to be more difficult to me: Assume that the shifted functions have (at least) one $x\in K$ such that the supremum is bigger or equal to $\varepsilon$. In this case we have to find $N'$ on another way (by my intuition by finding a N' on another compact interval), but I don't know how to write down this formally.

ANother possibility could be a proof by contradiction: Assume that the statement we want to prove is not correct, then we can find $t\in[0,s]$, a compact set K\subseteq\mathbb{R} and $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $N'\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $n\geq N'$ such that $\sup_{x\in K}{|f_n(x+t)|}\geq\varepsilon$. By this we should find a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in the compact set $K$ which allows us to find a convergent subsequence. This should leed to a contradiction with the first or second point above. But also here I can't find a formal way of writing down this.

I hope there will be some comments on this and maybe we can find a solution together. Thank you.

Comment: $K+t \subseteq \mathbb R_+$ is compact?

Comment: @user251257 : Yes I think so?!

Comment: I see: we can find $L\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq L$: $\sup_{x\in K+t}{|f_n(x)|}<\varepsilon$ and now take $N'=\max(N,L)$.

Comment: you don't have a $N$ just $L$. But the main idea is correct $\max_{N+t} |f| = \max_N |f(\cdot + t)|$.